# php pdo json encode array

Tags: php, json

hello I want to print "title" in the menu content data in the database, but I get an error. I do not know much about json, but as a result of my research, something like this came out and the error code is below

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in menu.php on line 59
```

mysql database data
**menu_content**

```
[{"title":"HelloWord","address":"HelloAdres","phone":"HelloPhone","submenu":[{"email":"HelloSubmenuEmail","phone":"HelloSubmenuPhone","fax":"HelloSubmenuFax"}]}]
```

**pdo**

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY menu_id DESC');
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**table**

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
<tr data-id="<?= $row['menu_id'] ?>">
<td width="90"><?= $row['menu_id'] ?></td>
<td width="90"><?= $row['menu_title'] ?></td>
<td><?php json_decode($row['menu_content']['title'],true) ?></td>
<td><?= $row['menu_date'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: `$row['menu_content']` has the JSON, not `title`. Also return that to a variable, otherwise it won't do anything for you.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert the JSON column before attempting to make use of its parts.

```
<tbody>
<?php 
foreach ($rows as $row): 
    $menu = json_decode($row['menu_content']);
?>
    <tr data-id="<?= $row['menu_id'] ?>">
        <td width="90"><?= $row['menu_id'] ?></td>
        <td width="90"><?= $row['menu_title'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $menu[0]->title ?></td>
        <td><?= $row['menu_date'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
endforeach; 
?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: so how do i get a submenu email ?

Comment: For example `$menu[0]->submenu[0]->email` But as its an array I assume you may have more than one so another foreach loop would be in order

Comment: RiggsFolly are you there?

Comment: @Mesut If you have a different question you should make a new post.

Answer (score 0):

Try is code :

```
 <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $menu_content=json_decode($row['menu_content'],true)
        ?>
    <tr data-id="<?= $row['menu_id'] ?>">
    <td width="90"><?= $row['menu_id'] ?></td>
    <td width="90"><?= $row['menu_title'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $menu_content[0]['title'];?></td>
    <td><?= $row['menu_date'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of what problem the code solves and why and not just "try this".

Comment: Inventor Bala are you there?

Comment: Yes, Mesut. Tell me what you want.